# Right trapeze in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, shapes

How can I move two lower nodes of the rectangle to get x1 = x2?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to go: You could use `Path > Path Effects > Perspective/Envelope`, check `Mirror Movements Vertical`, hold `Control`-Key while pulling the corner point with the `Edit Path by Nodes`-Tool.

Answer (score 4):

You can entry **manually** the [coordinates](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Coordinates.html) of each node.

Select the first node:

[image: Select first node]

**Input a new X**, e.g. **adding** 30 units to the existing value:

[image: Moved a node]

Then, **select the other node** and **remove the same amount** from the existing value of the X coordinate:

[image: Moved the other node]

Now, you have a right trapeze:

[image: Trapeze]

Comment: BTW as in most graphic software, the Inkscape entry fields allow calculations. E.g. you could enter "110.858 - 30".

Comment: @AAGD yes, indeed.